# How to unbatch a Tensorflow 2.0 Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset which I create with the following code working with `tf.data.Dataset`:

```
dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(corona_new)
dataset = dataset.window(WINDOW_SIZE, 1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(WINDOW_SIZE))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.transpose(x))

for i in dataset:
    print(i.numpy())
    break
```

which when I run it I get the following output (this is an example of one batch):

```
[[  0. 125. 111. 232. 164. 134. 235. 190.] 
 [  0.  14.  16.   7.   9.   7.   6.   8.]
 [  0. 132. 199. 158. 148. 141. 179. 174.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   2.   0.   2.   1.   2.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   3.   5.   0.   0.]]
```

How can I unbatch them?

Comment: what do you mean _flatten all batches into rows only?_

Comment: @NicolasGervais I'm bad with words sorry. I want to drop all batches or "unbatch".

Comment: That's why I was asking. You can just `.unbatch()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found my solution.

In TensorFlow 2.0 you can unbatch a `tf.data.Dataset` by calling the `.unbatch()` function.

example: `dataset.unbatch()`

Comment: Hah, yeah, you found it. The dataset class is nice, but really needs some better documentation.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren Yes! exactly! there's no tutorials or good doc out there at the moment.